# VXML <say-as > tag not working

Tags: sip, asterisk, ivr, vxml, voicexml

The  tag in VXML version=2.0 is not working i.e. not able to hear the text in  tag.

Hell World. Press  1  to repeat the message

I can hear the "Hello world. Press" and then silence and again continues from "to repeat the message." from Sip Client.

Please let me know if any further information required for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what TTS engine you are using but it could be that it does not like the "1".  Try spelling out the number 1 so the message is "Hello World. Press one to repeat the message."  Also if you are testing in a development environment on a workstation it may be that the system is picking up the audio from the IVR as input and bargein is kicking in and cutting of the prompt. Try setting bargein="false".  If neither of these are the issue then provide the complete VXML and a description of the IVR platform and environment used.